# Passing arguments as json object

Tags: json, django, azure, api, urllib

I am trying to link my django web app to Azure ML API. I do have Django form with all the required inputs for my Azure API.

```
def post(self,request):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    url = 'https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/7061a4b24ea64942a19f74ed36e4b438/services/ae2c257d6e164dca8d433ad1a1f9feb4/execute?api-version=2.0&format=swagger'

    api_key = # Replace this with the API key for the web service

    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ api_key)}

    if form.is_valid():
        age = form.cleaned_data['age']
        bmi = form.cleaned_data['bmi']
    args = {"age":age,"bmi":bmi}
    json_data = str.encode(json.dumps(args))
    print(type(json_data))

    r= urllib.request.Request(url,json_data,headers)
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(r)
        result = response.read()
        print(result) 
    except urllib.request.HTTPError as error:
        print("The request failed with status code: " + str(error.code))
        print(json_data)
        # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
        print(error.info())

        print(json.loads(error.read()))      
    return render(request,self.template_name)
```

When i try to submit the form i am getting type error -

```
TypeError('POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.',)
```

Getting status code - 400 and below error

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'Invalid argument provided.', 'details': [{'code': 'RequestBodyInvalid', 'message': 'No request body provided or error in deserializing the request body.'}]}}
```

Arguments are using print(json_data) -

```
b'{"age": 0, "bmi": 22.0}'
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you share your code with Json response, also, use JSON.stringify() method to convert postData value to a JSON string before you send a POST request.

Comment: Also you will get an exception when form is not valid due to bmi and age variables.

Comment: @JosefKorbel you are right.. but i guess over here arguments are not passed in the required json format.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JsonResponse:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Also, I don't think you need a template for API response.

```
return JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: thanks for quick view. I used JsonResponse but still i am getting status code 400 with reason as `'code': 'RequestBodyInvalid', 'message': 'No request body provided or error in deserializing the request body.'`

Comment: Use JSON.stringify() method to convert postData value to a JSON string before you send a POST request.

Comment: i am new to API... as u suggested i used `json_data = JsonResponse(args)`... please correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: Trying JSON.stringify() but getting error as JSON not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I found the error it was the data which was not in proper order.